# perl stat file from UNC path fails

Tags: perl, unc

It appears that perl will not accept a UNC path filename. Does anyone know of a workaround?

I tried both UNC and URL forms. Escaping the backslashes produces the same result as using just single backslashes.

```
13:35:39.28  C:\test\t
C:> perl -v | head -2 -

This is perl, v5.10.0 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

13:35:40.43  C:\test\t
C:> type ft.pl
#!/usr/bin/local/perl
use Time::localtime;

$mtime=(stat("ft.pl"))[9];
$t=localtime($mtime);
print sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", $t->year + 1900, $t->mon + 1, $t->mday, $t->hour, $t->min, $t->sec);

$mtime=(stat("\\\\zzz047922\\c$\\test\\t\\ft.pl"))[9];
$t=localtime($mtime);
print sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", $t->year + 1900, $t->mon + 1, $t->mday, $t->hour, $t->min, $t->sec);

$mtime=(stat("//zzz047922//c$/test/t/ft.pl"))[9];
$t=localtime($mtime);
print sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", $t->year + 1900, $t->mon + 1, $t->mday, $t->hour, $t->min, $t->sec);

13:35:50.62  C:\test\t
C:> perl ft.pl
2014-03-18 13:29:35
1969-12-31 17:00:00
1969-12-31 17:00:00
```

Many thanks, ikegami. I should have done that, but I was fixing a one-liner and did not think about it. Here is the resulting script.

```
M:> type getfiletimestamp.bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL
SET EXITCODE=0

IF "%1" == "" (ECHO usage: %0 ^<filename^> & SET EXITCODE=1 & GOTO TheEnd)
IF NOT EXIST "%1" (ECHO file "%1" does not exist & SET EXITCODE=2 & GOTO TheEnd)

SET FT=%~f1
SET F=%FT:\=/%
SET F=%F:$=\$%

perl -e "{use Time::localtime; $mtime=(stat(\"%F%\"))[9]; $t=localtime($mtime); print sprintf("%%04d-%%02d-%%02d %%02d:%%02d:%%02d\", $t->year + 1900
, $t->mon + 1, $t->mday, $t->hour, $t->min, $t->sec );}"

:TheEnd
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

Comment: As ikegami said, always [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in each and every script.  To fix the bug that warnings would alert you to, you can also use a single quoted string: `my $mtime=(stat('//zzz047922//c$/test/t/ft.pl'))[9];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

```
>type x.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "\\\\zzz047922\\c$\\test\\t\\ft.pl", "\n";

>perl x.pl
Use of uninitialized value $\ in concatenation (.) or string at x.pl line 3.
\\zzz047922\c   est\t\ft.pl
```

Now go escape the `$` or switch to single quotes.